# Video chat between two physical rooms without internet

Tags: video, chat

So I am a psychologist who would like to (without using the internet) chat with a client in the next room.  The only requirements would be they hear and see me and I hear and see them.  That is it!

I have set up a computer in my room (room 1)and have run a hd camera into the computer and using the basic windows camera app I can see but not hear them.  I have a television in the next room with a video in which connects to another camera in my office therefore they can see me too.  I had this working I but no sound transfer unfortunately. Is there some kind of software to support what seems to be a simple operation.

Basically I am trying to create a better than regular telehealth experience by using hd cams without lag or any internet connectivity issues.  Just live stream from one room to the next so with Covid we don't need to be in the same room.

Comment: What OS needs to be supported? And any pointers toward acceptable prices? Would e.g. 2 Android-tablets work (using a messenger working via WiFi direct – IIRC there were some such for "network independent use", maybe even able to create a mesh – I just don't remember where I saw that).

Comment: Something [here](https://www.fileguru.com/apps/video_lan_chat_without_internet_conection) may work for you.

Comment: Are these hd cams USB or what kind of connector.